# JSON - Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am not a JSON specialist and therefore I need help to solve a little problem.
When submitting a form, before the form closes, it returns **'Unexpected end of input'.**
I have searched the Internet and this forum, I found nothing solving the problem. I hope you'll be able to help me sort it out.

So, to make it easier for you, what's going on?
The user requests a listing. He fills the form with a message and a price. The item_id is transmitted directly (and working as I get it working so far).

The form data are sent via JSON to a remote server (VPS) which un-json the data. However, in addition to the 'unexpected end of input', I got on my remote server **'Server response: 400 (Bad Request)'**

I am almost sure it is due to this code and not the remote server one.
I have identified thanks to debug that the error is at the line :

**JSON.parse(data);**

```js
$('#requestListingSubmit').click(function (evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();
 rL_form.hide();
 rL_load.show();
 rL_controls.hide();
 rL_alert.empty();

 var item_id = $(this).data('item-id');   

 var route = '/request';
 $.ajax(
 {
  type: 'POST',
  url: coreURL + route,
  data: 
  {
   'item_id': item_id,
   'message': $('#message').val(),
   'price': $('#price').val(),
  },
  success: function (data) 
  {
   try 
   {
    JSON.parse(data);
    window.location = coreURL+'/account/listings?new';
   }
   catch(e) 
   {
    rL_load.hide();
    rL_form.show();
    rL_controls.show();
    rL_alert.alert(
    {
     type: 'danger',
     message: 'Error: '+e.message
    }); 
   }
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, status, httperror) {
   rL_load.hide();
   rL_form.show();
   rL_controls.show();
   rL_alert.alert({
    type: 'danger',
    message: (jqXHR.responseJSON.message || httperror)
   });
  }
 });

});
```

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: The random line of `JSON.parse(data);` Makes no sense...

Comment: 400 error would be caused by the request to the server. Is the server set up to handle a request as a post to the url? Is the url correct?

Comment: @epascarello : The server is communicating only with POST request. Requests are sent as POST and received as POST from the web server to the VPS server. However, the request sent from VPS to Web server are sent as POST and received as GET. 
I assumed it was due to this